# Touch Events on UIView on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, xamarin

I'm trying to catch the `touchesBegan` and the `touchesMoved` events on an UIView.
I have a UITableView; each cell contains a UIView with several controls. One of these controls is a subclass of a UIView with code in the `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` events.

If this control is not on the `tableviewcell`, then it works fine. But in this situation, all touches have effect to the tableview, but not to the UIView.

How to ignore the TouchEvents and redirect them to the UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one..

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
   if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourview])
   {
       return NO;
   }   
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'm working in Xamarin with C#. I don't know how to convert this code to C#

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `delaysContentTouches` property of the `tableview`(scrollview) to YES.